# jQuery - adding and removing classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make it so that there is a default tab, and when another is clicked, it takes the class off of that tab and onto the one that is clicked.

Here's the HTML that I have:

```
<div id="rightWrap">
    <div id="headStep"><span class="titleSub">Workers</span></div>
    <center>
    <br>
    <a href="../about/?s=architect"><table class="highlight">
    </table></a>
    <br>
    <a href="../about/?s=broker"><table class="">
    </table></a>
    <br>
    <a href="../about/?s=operator"><table class="">
    </table></a>
    <br>
    <a href="../about/?s=consultant"><table class="">
    </table></a>
    </center>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rightWrap a table').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify it to this;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rightWrap a table').click(function(){
        $('#rightWrap').find('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
        $(this).addClass('highlight');     
    });
});
```

Your HTML also needs some serious work.  Why the empty tables?

Answer (score 4):

Your tables are not siblings.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rightWrap a table').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parent().siblings('a').find('table').removeClass('highlight');
        $this.addClass('highlight');     
    });
});
```

Note that if the doctype of the page is not HTML5, wrapping the tables with `<a>` elements makes your document invalid.

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks for the edit, but there is no difference between the edited code and the original one.

Comment: In HTML5, it's perfectly legal to wrap a block level element (like a table) with an `<a>` tag and many browser have allowed this for awhile.  The empty tables are what make no sense to me.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, I know it's legal in HTML5, I think table tags have their on markup and OP hadn't posted them for brevity.